Units of electric field in quantum optics

Similarly, the expectation value for number operator in mode 4 is the same for a 50/50 beam splitter. This simply implies that the average number of photons in either one of the output ports is $50\%$, as expected. However, the expectation value
$$\langle \hat{N_3}\hat{N_4}\rangle = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} {_3}\langle1|_4\langle0| -\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}{_3}\langle0|_4\langle1| \right)\hat{a}_3^\dagger \hat{a}_3 \hat{a}_4^\dagger \hat{a}_4\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\langle1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4 + \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle_3|1\rangle_4\right) = 0. \tag{9}$$
This is a measure of the degree of second order coherence. This is simply a statement that a photon cannot be measured in two places simultaneously.
The expectation value of the electric field is
$$\langle\hat{E}_3(\chi)\rangle = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} {_3}\langle1|_4\langle0| -\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}{_3}\langle0|_4\langle1| \right)\left(\frac{1}{2} \hat{a}_3 e^{-i \chi} + \frac{1}{2} \hat{a}_3^\dagger e^{i \chi}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\langle1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4 + \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle_3|1\rangle_4\right) = 0. \tag{10}$$
This result is expected for an individual arm for the mean field. The electric field variance is then found to be
$$
\langle{\hat{E}_3}^2(\chi)\rangle = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} {_3}\langle1|_4\langle0| -\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}{_3}\langle0|_4\langle1| \right)\left(\frac{1}{2} \hat{a}_3 e^{-i \chi} + \frac{1}{2} \hat{a}_3^\dagger e^{i \chi}\right)^2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\langle1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4 + \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle_3|1\rangle_4\right) \\
= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} {_3}\langle1|_4\langle0| -\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}{_3}\langle0|_4\langle1| \right)(2 \hat{a}_3\dagger \hat{a}_3 +1) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\langle1\rangle_3|0\rangle_4 + \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle_3|1\rangle_4\right) = \frac{1}{2}.\tag{11}$$

In calculations like these, there are no units mentioned at the end. I understand usually we have Planck's constant and speed of light taken to be $1$, but in this case, when we are taking the expectation value of the electric field, it does not seem that we have taken those into account.
So, I am wondering if the result is $5.5$ at the end, as in the last equation. Is it $5.5 \,\text{W}\,\text{eV}\,\text{m}^{-1}$ or $5.5 \,\text{V}\,\text{m}^{-1}$?

In your original post the (11) that you took half of to get 5.5 was actually an equation number.

In calculations like these, there are no units mentioned at the end. That’s because they should be explained at the beginning. What is your source?

In quantum optics, your experimental result are usually in the form of a number of click (number of detected photons). From these results one would then calculate probabilities. Depending one what exactly is being measure you may eventually end up with a quantity with certain units, which you had to introduce in your calculation. You never measure the electric field directly in quantum optics.

@flippiefanus Regardless of whether it ever gets measured, the expectation value of the square of the electric field is calculated by the OP’s source, and presumably that calculation is in some meaningful system of units. The 1/2 almost certainly has nothing to do with SI units. I’ve never studied quantum optics, but using units where $\hbar=c=\omega=1$ seems like it would be a natural choice for photonic calculations.

@Ghoster I think you got it right, iirc $\hbar$, c etc are taken to be one in the beginning
